# Commutator $SU(2)$ generator and generic $SU(2)$ element, $[e^{i\frac{\sigma_i}{2}w^{i}},\sigma_{k}]=?$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra

I need to switch the matrix product $e^{i\frac{\sigma_i}{2}w^{i}}\sigma_{k}$  to prove explicitely an $SU(2)$ invariance. I don't want to pass to an infinitesimal transformation. However I completely don't know the result of the commutator:
$$[e^{i\frac{\sigma_i}{2}w^{i}},\sigma_{k}]=~?$$ 
Does someone know some useful relationship?

Comment: You know the [exponential of Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Exponential_of_a_Pauli_vector) is a linear function of them, no? The analog of Euler's formula.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Zachos, your availability is extraordinary!

Comment: Whenever you are stuck with commutators, it might be beneficial to see its action on a state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use such relation:
$$\omega = \exp(-i\alpha_a\sigma_a/2)
 = \cos(\alpha/2) - i(n_a\sigma_a)\sin(\alpha/2)$$
$$= \begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\alpha/2) - in_3\sin(\alpha/2) &
(-in_1-n_2)\sin(\alpha/2) \\
(-in_1+n_2)\sin(\alpha/2) &
\cos(\alpha/2) + in_3\sin(\alpha/2)
\end{pmatrix}$$

And easily calculate commutator:

$$
[e^{-i\alpha_a \sigma_a/2}, \sigma_b]
=
[\cos(\alpha/2)-i (n_a\sigma_a)\sin(\alpha/2), \sigma_b]
$$
$$
=
n_a\sin(\alpha/2)\varepsilon_{abc}\sigma_c
$$